# Delete MongoDB document from Express, Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My index.jade file(my button which the users clicks to delete the document) is:

```
a(href="/delete/#{booking.id}") Delete
```

So far in my index.js file is:

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
  Booking.findOneAndDelete({ id: req.params.id }).remove().exec();
});
```

I also, tried:

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
  Booking.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    message.type = 'Error!';
  }
  doc.remove(callback); //Removes the document
  });
```

Neither are working, I just get the url with the ID:

***localhost:3000/delete/54d49430b08883dc2fc8bb0d***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute before you can remove, you should also be performing a delete request and not a .get(). Try this:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
    Booking.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function(err, doc) {
            if (err || !doc) {
                res.statusCode = 404;
                res.send({});
            } else {
                doc.remove(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.statusCode = 403;
                        res.send(err);
                    } else {
                        res.send({});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, I'm still getting the url change but it isn't delete document out of the database

Comment: Is that id the valid id? Can you look in your network tab and see what response it's giving? Also add some console.log()'s in this delete method to see if doc is there.